# Extract version number of string

Tags: regex, shell, busybox

I'm trying to get the version number out of a string which looks like this:

```
[7:38:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.1.2
[7:38:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Published release 1.0.7 on default channel
```

As I need to do this in BusyBox, I can't use `grep` with the `-P` option:

```
grep -oP 'Published release \K.*? '
```

So I tried to use `sed`, but my attempt doesn't return anything:

```
sed -n 's/.*Published release (.*) .*/\1/p'
```

What is wrong with this command or is there a 'native' solution to get `1.0.7`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sed` like this:

```
sed -n 's/.*Published release \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file
```

See an [online demo](https://ideone.com/JHIfWF):

```sh
s='[7:38:06 PM] [semantic-release] › ℹ  Running semantic-release version 17.1.2
[7:38:09 PM] [semantic-release] › ✔  Published release 1.0.7 on default channel'
sed -n 's/.*Published release \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => 1.0.7
```

**Details**

- `-n` - suppresses the default line output
- `.*Published release \([^ ]*\).*` - matches

  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars
  - `Published release`  - a literal text
  - `\([^ ]*\)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a space
  - `.*` - any 0 or more chars
- `\1` - replaces with Group 1 value
- `p` - prints the result of the substitution

Answer (score 1):

You could use Busybox awk:

```
$ busybox awk '
match($0,/Published release [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)+/) {
    print substr($0,RSTART+18,RLENGTH-18)
}' file
```

Output:

```
1.0.7
```

Comment: It is nearly working. But as there are multiple output lines with multiple version values occuring, I need to check for the string `Published release`. So my post is not precise enough. I'm sorry for that.

Comment: Sure, fixing it now. A sec.

Answer (score 0):

If using sed, you must escape brackets:

```
sed -n 's/.*Published release \(\[.0-9\]+\).*/\1/'
```